# Error when using constant in defined function

Tags: c++, math, compilation, constants

I'm not a novice, but I may be making a novice mistake here. I'm writing code and I have declared a constant at the top of my program. Whenever I try to use that constant in one of my defined functions, I get an error.

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <fstream>;
#include <string>;
#include <cmath>;

#define PI 3.14159265358979323846;
#define RADI 300.0;

void CreatePieChart(unsigned char pixels[][WID][DEP], const int dims[3], 
double percentages[7], double radius)
{
    double radians, distance, deg;

    for (int i = 0; i < HITE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < WID; j++) {

            radians = get_theta(j, i, center);
            distance = get_distance_from_center(j, i, center, radians);
            deg = quadrant_converter(j, i, center, radians);

            if ( RADI < distance ) {
                pixels[i][j][0] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to access RADI I get an error.

1. Syntax Error: ')'
2. syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
3. '<' result of expression not used
4. language feature 'init-statements in if/switch' requires compiler flag '/std:c++17'

**All on the same line**

Please help.

Comment: Unrelated, what's with the semi-colons each standard header (one of which you included twice, for whatever reason) ?

Comment: Remove `;`s from `#define`s.

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry for that it was an accident doing it twice, and the semi-colons are an act of desperation.

Answer (score 1):

A #define literally replaces the thing on the left, with the thing on the right.

So when you write

```
#define RADI 300.0;
if ( RADI < distance )
```

that is the same as writing

```
if ( 300.0; < distance )
```

which has an extra `;` in the middle of it. Delete the `;`.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to delete the semi-colons after the headers and define declarations